# Can not post to ODataController derived controller but can to APIController derived controller

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

Using .Net Core 5 & Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 8.0.1 I have created a OData Web API endpoint.

When I base my controller off of the ODataController and I try to post a new record to a simple post end point the object I'm posting is empty. If I change the controller to be based on the ApiController the post works and I get the expected data.

```
public class NoteTypeController : ODataController (or ApiController)
  {
      [EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions=AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
      [HttpPost]
      public async Task<ActionResult<NoteType>> Post(NoteType noteType)
        {           
            return Created(noteType); //breakpoint here shows noteType empty 
        }
  }
```

Why would this be?

***** Edit
It seems to have something to do with how the json is formatted. If a value is not surrounded by quotes or if a value is empty/null then it will error out. i.e. because "true" is not quoted in the json below it will not work.

```
{
  "@odata.type":"MyModel.NoteType",
  "createdBy": "string",
  "modifiedBy": "string",
  "isActive": true,
  "description": "My Description"
}
```

Comment: Based on your edit, it seems this is effectively answered—i.e., that `ODataController` is fussier about how it deserializes the request, while `ApiController` offers more flexibility. If so, I wonder if your edit wouldn't be better served as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

ODataController is fussy about the format of the JSon being posted. Non-string values & null values must be quoted to work properly.